# RLP encoding of 0

Tags: pyethereum, rlp

According to the docs [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP),

> For a single byte whose value is in the [0x00, 0x7f] range, that byte
>   is its own RLP encoding

I ran the following using pyrlp (similar to the code in pyethereum [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/782842758e219e40739531a5e56fff6e63ca567b/ethereum/utils.py)):

```
res = rlp.encode([1, 0])
print ':'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in res)
```

and got a result of `c2:01:80`.
The `c2` refers to the list identifier (`c0` + 2 bytes for the following 2 elements). The `01` is obviously the first element in the array (1), encoded as itself. The 0 however is encoded to hex 80, which from my understanding of the documentation should not be the case.

I did notice in the examples on the RLP wiki that the null string encodes to hex 80, so is that factoring into this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that encoding the integer `0` no longer equates to `\x00` (as the documentation would imply). This can be seen both in your example, and in the fact that it can't be decoded:

```
>>> decode('\x00')
'\x00'
>>> decode('\x00', big_endian_int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rlp/codec.py", line 214, in decode
....
```

I think the typeless-ness of RLP encoding means that this shouldn't be an issue. Instead you can use `\x80` and a [sedes object](https://pyrlp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#sedes-objects) to specify the type:

```
>>> decode('\x80')
''
>>> decode('\x80', big_endian_int)
0
```

Comment: The RLP specification says that an integer zero should equate to the empty array (zero bytes)

Comment: @Sentinel Can you please cite the exact quote

Answer (score 2):

RLP is defined in [Ethereum Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) (Appendix A, page 16).

There are few interesting quotes:

> We define the RLP function as `RLP` through two sub-functions, the first handling the instance when the value is a byte array, the second when it is a sequence of further values
>
> If the byte-array contains fewer than 56 bytes, then the output is equal to the input prefixed by the byte equal to the length of the byte array plus 128
>
> If RLP is used to encode a scalar, defined only as a positive integer (`P` or any `x` for `Px`), it must be specified as the shortest byte array such that the big-endian interpretation of it is equal

The last one tells that leading zero bytes needs to be trimmed from big-endian representation of scalar values.

Scalar `0` is a special case - big-endian interpretation of `0` consists of zeros - so after trimming, we get empty byte array.
Empty byte array has length < 56, so it's length is encoded as `0+128` which is `0x80` in hex.

@bozzle as you quoted from documentation, byte array consisting of single byte with value `0x00` should be encoded as `0x00`. But scalar `0` is just a different case.